# How to properly update password in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

I have a Laravel application where I use a custom user authentication. Now i'm trying to allow user to update their password, the issue I'm running into there is that I need to check for the old password, if the field is not empty than I want to check if the new password matches the password repeat filed, if it does than update it here is the code I have in controller:

```
$newpass = $request->input('password');
$passrepeat = $request->input('passwordRepeat');

if ($oldPass = $request->input('oldPassword') != null)
{
  if (Hash::check($request->oldPassword, auth()->user()->password)){
       if ($newpass = $passrepeat){

                 $password = bcrypt($request['password']);
                 $user->password = $password;

       }
  }
}
```

and then I update it:

```
$user->update();
```

But my code seem to not even check for the password field. I'm clearly making mistakes when I check for the oldPassword field. There are just too many options that I can try so I decided ask as a question.

> Laravel 5.4

Comment: http://teamnik.org/how-to-update-user-password-in-laravel5/

Comment: Yeah this is good example, But there is one problem, In my case there are more input fields and user might completaly skip updating password, but if it decides to update it than I ckec for the oldPassword filed and if its filled and matches old password than I reset it

Answer (score 3):

From [the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/hashing#basic-usage):

> The `check` method allows you to verify that a given plain-text string corresponds to a given hash. However, if you are using the `LoginController` included with Laravel, you will probably not need to use this directly, as this controller automatically calls this method:

```
if (Hash::check('plain-text', $hashedPassword)) {
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/hashing#basic-usage

Comment: Can I do this with Hash::check? `if (Hash::check($request->input('oldPassword', Auth::User()->getAuthPassword() ) )){`

Comment: @Nikonah `if (Hash::check($request->oldPassword), auth()->user()->password))`

Comment: Well that worked. thanks for the help. btw you made a typo error in that comment it should be `if (Hash::check($request->oldPassword, auth()->user()->password))`

Comment: Nah there is an issue. it just passes that stage and updates password, the weird thing is it doesn't even check if new password and repeat matches. I'm updating the question for how it looks now.

Answer (score 0):

Just Replace these two lines

```
  $password = bcrypt($request['password']);
  $user->password = $password;
```

With

```
 $user->password = password_hash($request->password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
```

Comment: it still doesnt fix the oldpassword check issue. this line `if ($oldPass = $request->input('oldPassword') != null)` just skips and does the update